# Python does not skip "if [strg] or [strg] in variable"

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a simple text-based game in Python 2.7. In the code below, even if the user answers something completely different than "run" or "nothing," the `arrested()` function still kicks in. I'm pretty sure the problem is in this line of code:

```
if "run" or "nothing" in answer:
```

because if I only provide one string, as follows:

```
if "run" in answer:
```

the program runs beautifully, calling `remote_spot()` if the answer does not contain "run". The whole code is the following:

```
def facing_cops():
    print "There are several cars that might serve as stake-outs for the cops. What do you do?"
    answer = raw_input("> ")
    if "run" or "nothing" in answer:
        arrested("Cops got suspicious. You are arrested, along with the drug dealer.")
    else:
        remote_spot()
```

What do you think is the matter?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator 'in' has priority over 'or' so that you're effectively testing `if "run" or ("nothing" in answer)`. If you only have two, you can well write:

```
if "run" in answer or "nothing" in answer:
```

If ever you have more keywords to test than 2, things get a bit long to write and you could go for this option:

```
keywords = ["run","nothing","otherkeyword"]
if any(keyword in answer for keyword in keywords):
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I'd vote your answer up but I do not seem to have the reputation required to do so.

Comment: Just mark the answer as accepted, it will do :)

Answer (score 3):

The `or` does not do what you want it to do. What you wrote is the same as:

```
if "run" or ("nothing" in answer):
```

"run" is a string and in a boolean context it is understood as True. So you want:

```
if "run" in answer or "nothing" in answer:
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! I'd vote your answer up but I do not seem to have the reputation required to do so.

Comment: You can accept an answer that solved your problem.

Comment: How do I do that? :)